# Distance matrix only for a specific rule [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am having a hard time using distance matrix vector tool in QGIS for a specific need.

I know you need to have two different point layers in order to get a distance matrix, so far so good.

But as I have 3 000 points in one layer and 568 points in the other layer, and only need to calculate the distance between one point to another one, I would like to be able to get the distance matrix rule based.

As an exemple, i would like to set a rule like this: 
IF Layer 1 - Column A = Layer 2 - Column B then execute the distance matrix calculation between those points.

Can I do this in qgis ?

QGIS version 3.8.3

Comment: Have you tried creating subsets using `select by expression`?

Comment: I thought of it, but in my "easiest" layer that would mean 25+ subsets

Comment: Could be done, if you don't have to repeat the process?

Comment: Actually it has to be repeated twelve times. With each time a different number of subset.That's why I'am looking for a less time consuming trick